# Jackson2JsonMessageConverter not work for rabbitmq

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I use following code for message converter:

```
SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory  connectionFactory, Queue queue,
        MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter) {

    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    container.setQueueNames(queue.getName());
    container.setMessageListener(listenerAdapter);
    container.setMessageConverter(new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter());
    return container;
}
```

My listener is declared:

```
public void receiveMessage(List<Map<String, Object>> message) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Received <" + new String(message, "UTF-8") +     ">");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But it always try to gives follow error:

```
Failed to invoke target method 'receiveMessage' with argument type = [class [B], value = [{[B@40c2d9c5}]","at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter.invokeListenerMethod(MessageListenerAdapter.java:408)
```

It seems it tries to invoke byte[] as argument instead of convert json string to List>.

Answer (score 5):

The converter requires a `content_type` message property that contains the token `json` - e.g. `application/json`. You should see a WARN log if you are using at least version 1.6.1.

```
log.warn("Could not convert incoming message with content-type ["
        + contentType + "], 'json' keyword missing.");
```

If you can't change the producer to set the content type properly, you can subclass the converter...

```
@Override
public Object fromMessage(Message message, Object conversionHint) throws MessageConversionException {
    message.getMessageProperties().setContentType("application/json");
    return super.fromMessage(message, conversionHint);
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you don't understand; I said create a subclass of `Jackson2JsonMessageConverter` and override that method as shown. It's rude to down-vote a clear answer.